# Update domain of column with primary key without dropping constraint in Firebird

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, constraints, primary-key, firebird

Is it possible to update columns with constraints without dropping them? I want to change domain of columns with primary keys and foreign keys.

Now I only found solution with dropping constraints, what looks like a long way to do it, because I also need to drop FK's which depends on my primary key and after restore them,  and I want to simplify this way.

I'm using Firebird 2.5

Comment: Did you try `ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN col TYPE newType`? If that doesn't work then I'm afraid there is no other way than dropping constraints... or hacking system tables.

Comment: I'd need to test it, but I believe if you are using a domain, and both the FK and PK use that domain, then yes, otherwise no.

Comment: @ain Hacking system tables is not a very good idea, especially not when changing data types; and Firebird 3 disallows it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel oh, I absolutely agree, I just pointed it out that if he is hell bent to do it without droping the constraint, there is a way...